# Retrieving number phrases

Tags: c++, sapi

I found this another post on here, but I couldn't comment on it. It is a grammar file that has numbers. How would I retrieve the numbers? I know I can use `wcscmp` function, but let us say there are 200 numbers; that would be a lot of `if else` statements within each other. How would I be able to also search the pPhrase->Rule rule hierarchy and assign a rule pointer.

**Note** this can have another rule with another set of numbers to be able to ascertain multiple digits.

Here is the snippet of the grammar file; however, I changed the numbers that are not within quotations into worded numbers.

```
<rule name="phoneno">
  <phrase min="7" max="10">
    <ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
  </phrase>
</rule>

<rule name="digit">
  <l>
    <p val="0">zero</p>
    <p val="1">one</p>
    <p val="2">two</p>
    <p val="3">three</p>
    <p val="4">four</p>
    <p val="5">five</p>
    <p val="6">six</p>
    <p val="7">seven</p>
    <p val="8">eight</p>
    <p val="9">nine</p>
  </l>
</rule>
```

**EDIT** Snippet of the Code to retrieve and process certain phrases.

```
SPPHRASE *pElements;
std::wstring str;

// Get the phrase elements, one of which is the rule id we specified in
// the grammar.  Switch on it to figure out which command was recognized.

if (SUCCEEDED(pPrhase->GetPhrase(&pElements))) {
    SPPHRASE phrase = *pElements;
    WCHAR *pText;
    const SPPHRASEPROPERTY *pProp = phrase.pProperties;

    if (SUCCEEDED(pPhrase->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, TRUE, &pText, NULL))) {
        str = pText;
    }
    else {

    }
}

switch (pElements->Rule.ulId) {
    case digit:
        while (pProp != NULL) {
            if (wcscmp(L"digit", phrase.Rule.pszName) == 0) {
                if (wcscmp(L"one", pProp->pFirstChild->pszValue) == 0) {
                    pProp = pProp->pNextSibling;
                }
                else if (wcscmp(L"two", pProp->pFirstChild->pszValue) == 0) {
                    pProp = pProp->pNextSibling;
                }
                else if (wcscmp(L"three", pProp->pFirstChild->pszValue) == 0) {
                    pProp = pProp->pNextSibling;
                }
                // all the way up to nine
            }
            // now let us say there is a another digit after the first digit. 
            // so the number can be from 11 - 99, would I need to place the second digit
            // within each of the "first digit if / else if statements"?    Or is there
            // an efficient way to do this? 
            }
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point it becomes easier to use microsoft's grammar compiler (gc.exe) to generate a list of IDs so you can easily just compare IDs and not go by rule names. The end result in code would look something like:

```
SPPHRASE *pElements;

// Get the phrase elements, one of which is the rule id we specified in
// the grammar.  Switch on it to figure out which command was recognized.
if (SUCCEEDED(pPhrase->GetPhrase(&pElements)))
{        
    switch ( pElements->Rule.ulId )
    {
        case VID_RuleNameHere:
        {
           //Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

You can read up more on how to do that [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) You'll also want to specify the /H switch when you run gc.exe against your grammar file.

Comment: I did an edit to my original question; adding the C++ portion. Would what I just posted be correct? And how would I do multiple digits? I would like to stay in this type of format. 

Also, I'm not too entirely sure that I am using the `pProp = pProp->pNextSibling` correctly.

Comment: For entirely a set of numbers you could just make each one an individual rule for each that corresponds to the Rule.ulId and then you can just do an atoi(Rule.uIId).

Comment: For multiple digits you could just define a new rule that had multiple digits, like

<RULE NAME="MultipleDigits" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
<ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
<ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
<ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
</RULE>

Which would listen for specifically three digits